# How to Pull and Push Multiple Docker Images using Shell Script?

Tags: docker, image, shell, jenkins, gitlab

I have created a code to pull, tag and push single docker image. It is working well. If the image does not exist, the docker pull fails. If the image is valid and new, it will get pushed to the required repo. Else if the image already exists, we will take back up of it and push.

Now I have to make that possible for multiple images. I do not know how to do it.
Here is a small snippet ( I have removed certain parts as I cannot show it)

```
docker pull ${docker_image}
                      image_name=$(echo "${docker_image}" | cut -d / -f 2-)
                      echo $image_name
         
                      if docker pull "${D_path}/${image_name}" 2>&1 | grep -E '(not found|no such|unable to|ERROR)' >/dev/null; then
                        echo "not exist"
                        
                        docker tag 
                        docker push
                      else
                        echo "image exist , we are taking backup of the image "
                        docker pull 
                        docker tag 
                        docker push
                      fi
```

I read of this command "
for image in $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}"); do docker pull $image; done".
However, I am not sure if it will work.

Comment: I think `for image in $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}"); do docker pull $image; done` this should work. You can perform a sanity check of the above command, just replace `docker pull $image` with `echo "Image==> $image"` and check if it prints all the image names

Comment: Hi thankyou. Which line do I put that command?

Comment: You can try running the command itself without modifying your shell script.
Just copy and paste it on the terminal `for image in $(docker images --format "{{.Repository}}"); do echo "Image==> $image"; done`. But keep in mind about `{{.Repository}}`

Comment: Hi. I tried it and it does not do what I require. It only formats the docker image output.

Comment: `for img in img1 img2 img3; do docker pull $img; done`